# Bootstrap multi-select select all option value

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap-multiselect plugin.

**jQuery**

```
$("#country").multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    numberDisplayed: 2,
    maxHeight: 400,
    buttonWidth: '100%',
    selectAllValue: '0'
});
```

when I select the select all option and submit the code i get an array of all other options in server side.But i am assigning the value 0 for the select all option which i am not getting in server side.How can i include the value 0 in the value array when i select the select all option.

Comment: Can you try this: selectAllValue: 0

Comment: @NeerPriv yes i tried but result is the same

Comment: can set the value for the "Select all"  with the "selectAllValue" option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in the [Server Side Processing](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#post) section of the documentation, the `selectAllValue` merely alters the value submitted. However, in order to correctly submit the select all option, you have to set the name of the select all option using [`selectAllName`](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-selectAllName). Btw: when aiming to process the multiselect data server side, you should also use [`checkboxName`](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-checkboxName).